# LDAP client mixing up credentials

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have installed openLDAP using this https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-ubuntu-server-20-04/on a Ubuntu 20.04 Serverand Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop has a client installed using https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-ldap-client/

Login of local user "client" works and so does LDAP user "evhalen" However sometimes when I open terminal in the client it shows the other user on the prompt, so login in on GUI as "client" and in terminal it shows "evanhalen" as users and confirms this with whoami.

I have made 2 local users on the Ubuntu workstation, log off and switching to other local user few times no problem.

Problem only occurs once I login with the user I made on the LDAP server, then it does show correct name on home folder but in the terminal it shows the previous user. Also if the screenlocks it shows the user from the terminal prompt instead of the user I login with (and accepts psw for user I logged in as)

So basicly login as user 1 , terminal shows user 2 and lockscreen shows user 2. Unlock screen with psw of user 1.

Reboot fixes it till I login with LDAP account.

All installed on my homelab running VM esxi 6.5

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it working.

I started all over on new VM, replaced `libnss-ldap` with `libnss-ldapd` (mark the **`d`**) as it says as comment on the instructions above, only selected passwd, group and shadow during configuration step when install asks which services to configure.